# How to use nested functions as generator in javascript (using "inner" yields)

Tags: javascript, generator, inner-classes, yield-keyword

```
<script>
function * d1 (p)  {
    p-=1;
    yield p;
    p-=2;
    yield p;
}

var g=d1 (9);
var h;
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
</script>
```

gives  8,false; then 6,false; then undefined,true;
whereas

```
<script>
function * d2 (p)     {
    function * d1 (p)     {
        p -=1 ;
        yield p;
        p -=2 ;
        yield p;
    }
    d1(p);
}
var g=d2 (9);
var h;
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
</script>
```

gives me three times undefined,true;

As I want the hidden structure of d1 (as inner-function), how can I proceed to still have the same result as on the first sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d2` generator function doesn't yield nor return anything, so you only get undefined.

You probably want to call it passing `p` argument, and yield each iterated value with `yield*`.

```
function * d2 (p) {
  yield* function * d1 (p) {
    p -= 1;
    yield p;
    p -= 2;
    yield p;
  }(p);
}
```

Comment: So   <script>
 function * d2 (p) {
 .... code  }
 var g=d2 (9);
 var h;
 console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
 console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
 console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
 console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
 </script>
     is fine for me.          I understand now that 'yield' is more a 'return' than a 'stop here for synchronisation'.  I will have to dig for the expression " yield * ", which is new for me and does the job as kind of additional 'indirection'.     ...***...        So it is a 3 stars solution ;-)  ...***...

Comment: `yield* iterable` behaves like `for(let value of iterable) yield value;`

Answer (score 0):

For copy and past needs: that is the solution of Oriol working for me

```
<script>
function * d2 (p)     {
    function * d1 (p)     {
        p -=1 ;
        yield p;
        p -=2 ;
        yield p;          }
    yield * d1(p);    }
 // ^^^^^^^^ are the changes
var g=d2 (9);
var h;
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
console.log((h=g.next()).value+','+h.done+';');
</script>
```